# llvm Won't generate debug line information

Tags: c++, llvm

I have the following code:

```
llvmbuilder->SetCurrentDebugLocation(llvm::DILocation::get(*llvmctx, 0, mypos, llvmsub));
```

Where `llvmsub` is constructed at each function definition beginning like so:

```
llvmsub = llvm::DISubprogram::getDistinct(*llvmctx, llvmcu->getFile(), currfunc->identifier, currfunc->linkage, llvmcu->getFile(), 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, 0, llvm::DINode::DIFlags::FlagZero, llvm::DISubprogram::toSPFlags(false, true, false), llvmcu);
```

Where `currfunc->identifier, currfunc->linkage` are strings - for my C function and `llvmcu` is defined as follows, in the beginning of my Translation Unit:

```
llvmcu = llvmdibuilder->createCompileUnit(llvm::dwarf::DW_LANG_C, llvmdibuilder->createFile(std::string{modulename}, ""), "regularc", false, "", 0);
```

I also set version like so:

```
mainmodule->addModuleFlag(llvm::Module::Warning, "Debug Info Version",
                           llvm::DEBUG_METADATA_VERSION);
```

The issue is that after generation (which looks like this):

```
0 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C, file: !1, producer: "regularc", isOptimized: false, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug)
!1 = !DIFile(filename: "combined.pp_1", directory: "")
!2 = !{i32 2, !"Debug Info Version", i32 3}
!3 = !DILocation(line: 0, column: 49179, scope: !4)
!4 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "checkkeyb", scope: !1, file: !1, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition, unit: !0)
!5 = !DILocation(line: 0, column: 49215, scope: !4)
!6 = !DILocation(line: 0, column: 49227, scope: !4)
!7 = !DILocation(line: 0, column: 49241, scope: !4)
!8 = !DILocation(line: 0, column: 49255, scope: !4)
!9 = !DILocation(line: 0, column: 49288, scope: !4)
```

(The columns are so long because I actually store file offsets)

After I compiler with `llc` and then with `clang -g` I get no debug line information in lldb:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100126cb0 libSDL-1.2.0.dylib`SDL_SetColorKey + 36
    frame #1: 0x000000010000b444 a.out`vgainit + 76
    frame #2: 0x000000010000f354 a.out`maininit + 28
    frame #3: 0x000000010000fd48 a.out`main + 20
    frame #4: 0x00000001ac887e50 dyld`start + 2544
```

Comment: A "line 0" location means that it is not possible to associate the instruction to a single line. Debuggers tend to ignore these locations. Try using a line number different from 0.

Comment: Also, one thing you could do to check if the debug information is present is to look for the dwarf directives in llc's output.